# Filepicker.io uploads failing for resources > 1.6 MB

Tags: filepicker.io

This morning we noticed that our filepicker.io uploads are no longer processing if the size of the file is greater than ~1.6MB. Not sure if it's related to the recent upgrade of the Javascript API (v1) but at the moment our users are unable to upload files.

The POST request to filepicker returns a 200 but the progress bar just halts at 99.30%. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We're looking into this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to officially mark this as fixed so we don't have unresolved questions! Feel free to mark as answered or remove

Comment: Will do! Thanks again for all the help. Keep up the great work fellas.